How to print the textpayload log error message into the Slack notifncation channel in gcp monitoring
We are implementing monitoring for our data pipeline so that if it breaks in the future, a notification is sent to our Slack channel.
I have successfully included all the required parameters in the notification message, but I am stuck on displaying the exact error message that caused the function to break.
Specifically, I tried to include the textPayload field from Google Cloud Function logs in a Slack notification triggered by a Google Cloud Monitoring alert. However, despite using ${textPayload} in the alert documentation section, the notification does not display the actual error message from the logs. Instead, it shows the placeholder ${textPayload}.
{
"severity": "ERROR",
"textPayload": "Traceback (most recent call last): ...",
"resource": {
"type": "cloud_function"
}
}
when i Setting ${textPayload} directly in the alert documentation content.
"content": "Error Message: ${textPayload}"
this is not woking.
Going through the logging docs, and I can't see to find anything that can be used. Is something like this possible or will it require some more complexity?
How can I dynamically include the textPayload field in my Slack notifications for Google Cloud Monitoring alerts?

Shouldn't it be `Error Message: ${textPayload}` ? Note that I'm using template literals and not double quote
